# Do Rippers PCs get one or two starting Edges?

Tags: character-creation, savage-worlds

I've been running Rippers for a few sessions now and just brought on a new player. They noticed that the SWD book states humans "start play with one free Edge." I was previously allowing one free edge during character creation since the Rippers book states "Your hero gets one free Edge, plus any additional Edges you purchase with Hindrance points."

I've had all PCs roll humans for this game, but I'm a little unsure about the number of 'free' edges they should receive during character creation. Should it be two? One for human from SWD and one from Rippers setting. Or should it be one and each mention shouldn't be counted individually?

Answer (score 8):

The rules for Edge creation in general for Savage Worlds are clarified on the [PEG forums in “How many starting edges?”](http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=28845), which just confirms that all humans get one extra starting Edge.

I believe that all characters would at least start as human, so I would assume the character creation rules remind people of their starting human Edge, rather than giving them an additional Edge on top of that.

Comment: Agreed. The Rippers rules are simply reminding you that as humans, Rippers start with that free Edge

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I mainly didn't want to be withholding an advantage from the players for this. Thanks!